# readFile and file_get_contents render corrupted PDF and PNG files but JPG are good

Tags: php

I've developped an application which allows users to associate pictures with articles. After the association, the user has two possibilities, whether he download the associated pictures (which are globally PDF, JPG or PNG files) or he triggers an email towards himself. 
Actually,I have two problems: 
-> whenever I try to get the file contents like this:

```
/**
 * Renvoie le flux correspondant à l'URL passée en paramètre
 * @param $url url complète du fichier à récupérer en HTTP
 * @return string
 */
private function getHTTPFile($url) {
    // Accès à un fichier HTTP avec les entêtes HTTP indiqués ci-dessus
    return file_get_contents($url);
}
```

The file content is systematically false for both PDF or PNG Files, but it is ok for JPG files.
-> Whenever I download the files, the problem is similar and both PDF and PNG files are corrupted.

```
<?php

$linkLogo = $_REQUEST['_link'];

if ($linkLogo) {
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($linkLogo) ."\"");
    if (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    readfile ($linkLogo);
    exit();
}
?>
```

I wonder if the problem is not the fact that PDF and PNG are both binary files.

NB: I built a PDF file from an image inserted in a Word File and it worked fine. May be the problem is the read rights on the binary files or configuration on apache server. Please Help.

Comment: save these corrupt files to disk if you haven't already and open them as a text file - they will most likely contain an error message and/or extra whitespace rendering them invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the problem was the fact that I got spaces in the name of the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced spaces with %20

```
<?php

$linkLogo = $_REQUEST['_link'];

if ($linkLogo) {
    $linkLogo = str_replace(' ', '%20', $linkLogo);
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($_REQUEST['_link']) ."\"");
    if (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    readfile ($linkLogo);
    exit();
}
?>
```